# Restrict access to SocketCAN to a certain user group

Tags: permissions, iptables, access-control

I have a PC to which a robot is connected via CAN (using SocketCAN).  I'd like to control who can send commands to the robot, ideally through a group (i.e. only users who are in the "use_robot" group have permission to send/receive anything via CAN).

How can I achieve this?  To my understanding, SocketCAN uses network interfaces so, probably somehow with iptables?

Comment: While I am not positive, the `ip` in `iptables` suggests that it won't be particularly useful for CAN networks.

Comment: Well, the `ip` command is used to configure the CAN interfaces, so it doesn't seem too unlikely.  I'm just not very familiar with iptables, otherwise I would simply give it a try.

Comment: I did a few tests: using nftables' netdev egress (kernel >= 5.16) it's easy to limit per uid emission. What I don't know how to do is to limit *reception*. I got a python example to emit traffic through can (https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#python-can), but I don't have anything to listen to traffic to do further testing (who knows? sockets and cgroups?)

Comment: @A.B For my use case it would actually be enough if I can prevent users from sending something to the robot (as they could potentially damage it).  If they can still receive data from the robot, that wouldn't be a problem for me.

Comment: @A.B you can use `cangen` and `candump` from the [`can-utils`](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils) project to generate and listen to traffic for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to control who can send commands to the robot, ideally through a group...

I spent a little bit of time looking at this today. I can prevent members of a group from *sending* traffic to a CAN interface using an nftables ruleset like this:

```
table netdev canfilter {
        chain can1egress {
                type filter hook egress device can1 priority filter; policy accept;
                skgid 1000 counter drop;
        }
}
```

(The `counter` in the above ruleset isn't necessary; it just adds a packet count to the output of `nft list ruleset`.)

This prevents members of group 1000 from sending via the `can1` interface. If I try running `cangen can1` as a user with gid 1000, I see:

```
$ sudo -u testuser cangen can1
write: No buffer space available
```

Whereas if I do the same thing as a user not in that group, it works without errors (and I can receive the traffic using `candump` on another link).

I think that accomplishes your goal.

---

I don't think it's possible to limit *reception* by uid; looking at the logs produced using something like:

```
table netdev canfilter {
        chain can0ingress {
                type filter hook ingress device can0 priority filter; policy accept;
                log group 0;
        }
}
```

It looks like on the receiving side we don't have access to the uid/gid metadata (which makes sense, because packets may be arriving from other than the local system).

---

For testing this out, I used the `cangen` and `candump` utilities from the [`can-utils`](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils) project, and [`ulogd`](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/ulogd/) for logging since I was using isolated namespaces for the CAN interfaces (so regular kernel logging wasn't an option).

---

I've streamlined my test and put everything online [here](https://github.com/larsks/unixse-example-751134-can-filtering).